# Laravel 5 and Socialite, how to save in the database and log-in

Tags: php, laravel

After reading: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication I was able to retrieve the user details from the OAuth provider (Facebook) using Socialite:

```
$user->getNickname();
$user->getName();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getAvatar();
```

But I couldn't find any further documentation on how to save the user in the database or log the user in.

I want to do the equivalent to:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])
```

But for the details retrieved via Socialite (I don't have a password)

Can you please show me an example on using "Auth" with user data retrieved via Socialite?

Comment: It depends on how you want to authenticate the user. If you need the user to grant login with just the facebook email you need to ask for a password and save it along with the user.  If you are not asking for a password save just the token and the fb id which then you can use to direct the user to the profile when the user has logged in the second time. You need to save the token on your handleProviderCallback function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add to "**users**" table new column: **facebook_user_id**. Every time when user tries to login through Facebook, Facebook will return the same user id.

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $socialize_user = Socialize::with($provider)->user();
    $facebook_user_id = $socialize_user->getId(); // unique facebook user id

    $user = User::where('facebook_user_id', $facebook_user_id)->first();

    // register (if no user)
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->facebook_id = $facebook_user_id;
        $user->save();
    }

    // login
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

---

**How Laravel Socialite works?**

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
   // 1. with this method you redirect user to facebook, twitter... to get permission to use user data
   return Socialize::with('github')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
   // 2. facebook, twitter... redirects user here, where you write code to log in user
   $user = Socialize::with('github')->user();
}
```

Comment: what if the user decides not to login using facebook for once? They can only signin using facebook in this way right?

Comment: you can leave regular login also, users will chose what they want :)

Comment: Just want to add that you'll want to use BIGINT for storing the returned facebook user id. A typical id looks like 10153582596228606 which cannot fit inside a 4 byte int